# Generalizing a Telescoping Sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

I was trying to generalize an integral I found yesterday on this website and ran into the following interesting sum:

$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}$.  I have seen this sum come up a lot in my calculus classes but today I realized it converges for all $k \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  I was only able to prove that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that $S_k = -H_k$ where $H_k$ is the $k^{th}$ harmonic number.  My proof is by induction on k and is as follows:

The base case is $S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}$ which if one writes out the terms clearly telescope to -1 while $-H_1=-1$.  Now I assume $S_k = -H_k$ and note that $S_{k+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1}-\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.  Reindexing the first sum to $n=2$ and throwing out the first term in the harmonic sum gives, $-1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=-1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}$.  Now the remaining the sum is just $S_k$ but without the first term so we may rewrite this as $-1+(S_k-(\frac{1}{k+1}-1))$ simplifying and using the inductive assumption that $S_k = -H_k$ we have that $S_{k+1}=-H_k-\frac{1}{k+1}=-H_{k+1}$ so the result holds by induction.

So now my question is does anyone have a result for $k \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $k \in \mathbb{I}$?  It looks as though Mathematica is cabable of finding a closed form for any $k \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization

Comment: Wow!  I really need to start looking into special functions before I post questions!  So this is really just a special case of the digamma function is what I'm gathering?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split the sums as you want in your inductive step, because the harmonic series diverges.

You can do it like this, involving two convergent sums: 
\begin{align}
S_{k+1}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1}-\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1}-\frac1{n+k}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}\\ \ \\
&=-\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}\\ \ \\
&=-\frac1{k+1}-H_k=-H_{k+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Wow that is slick.  So by adding a clever 0 you can avoid ever having a divergent sum in your calculations.

Comment: It is worth noting that the proper proof for telescopic sums involves looking at finite sums and *then* taking the limit (e.g., $$\sum_{n=1}^Na_{n+1}-a_n=\sum_{n=1}^Na_{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=-a_1+a_{N+1}$$ and now take the limit as $N\to\infty$). The generalization is then $$\sum_{n=1}^Na_{n+k}-a_n=-\left(\sum_{n=1}^ka_n\right)+\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+k}a_{n}.$$ In particular, although TC's writing is not spot on, it is the usual approach.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you for your comment.  I have not had much analysis but I remember this sort of technique for proving that the geometric sum converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $-1<x<1$.